# Subset and summarize dataset to prepare visualization for stacked area graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, aggregate

I have a dataset with 800k rows, each with a timestamp. The data covers a timeframe of one year.

In preparation of a stacked area graph I want to produce, I want to create 26 subgroups (e.g. two week intervals). Within these subgroups I want to find the frequency of values within 5 classes.

As an example: In the first two weeks, what percentage of the values were > x && <= y, how many were > y && <= z etc.

All this is supposed to lead to a stacked area graph created by the ggplot2 library and its geom_area() function.

Here's the head of the data-set:

```
     date transaction_volume transaction_costs

47 2015-01-01           3.985826           0.03157
59 2015-01-01           3.955749           0.03157
71 2015-01-01           0.315700           0.03157
72 2015-01-01           0.315700           0.03157
73 2015-01-01           0.315700           0.03157
74 2015-01-01           0.315700           0.03157
```

Comment: It would help if you showed us your data (e.g. at least the `head`), or provide a reproducible example.

Comment: You're right, I've added the output from head()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example with some dummy data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

n <- 1000
d <- data.frame(date=as.Date('2010/01/01') + sort(sample(0:364, n, replace=TRUE)))
d$x <- runif(n)

# These are the breaks defining your bins of data    
breaks <- c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)

d %>% 
  # create fortnight indicator from Julian day number
  mutate(Fortnight=ceiling(as.numeric(format(date, '%j'))/14)) %>%
  # bin data
  mutate(Class=factor(findInterval(x, breaks))) %>%
  group_by(Fortnight, Class) %>%
  # count per group
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  # expressed as proportions
  mutate(Proportion=n/sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Fortnight, y=Proportion, fill=Class)) + 
    geom_area()
```

[image]

Filter out fortnight 27 if you want to clean it up a bit. E.g. inserting `filter(Fortnight < 27) %>%` before the `ggplot` call.

Comment: @Max Schumacher you may want to give jbaums an up vote to thank him a little more :-)

Comment: @steveb - I think there's a rep requirement for voting privileges ;)

Comment: @jbaums, Ahhh, I see, he is just short a few points.  Thanks for the correction.  I have gotten answers from SO for a long time but I am new to participating.